# Как по нажатию кнопки разблокировать поле ввода?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, button, react-native

Всем привет. Я новичок и хочу сделать активным поле ввода при нажатии на кнопку. Делаю все это я на react:

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="dog" id="ch" readOnly />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="RENAME DOG" name="get dog" />
</div>
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример основ React - https://codepen.io/latdev/pen/mdBbjxQ

```
const {useState} = React; // import {useState} from "react"

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Rex");
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState("disabled");
  return <div id="app">
    <div style={{marginTop: "20px"}}>
      <input type="text" value={name} name="dog" disabled={disabled} onChange={event => setName(event.target.value)} />
    </div>
    <div style={{marginTop: "10px"}}>
      <button onClick={_ => setDisabled(disabled !== null ? null : "disabled")}>{disabled !== null ? "RENAME DOG" : "Save Dog Name"}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ. Я вот не могу понять условие изменения , хотя с хуками я знаком если можно опиши пожалуйста в двух словах. И это у меня находиться в компоненте которая берет данные с бека и засовывает их в массив . На странице выводит изображение . Так вот когда я нажимаю RENAME DOG то вся страница обновляется . (Нужен preventdefault ?) И что эта запись означает ({_ =>) ?

Comment: Видимо он у тебя кнопку считает как `type="submit"` от туда и пытается перезагрузить страницу, да можно через `Event.preventDefault()` отменить любой event и субмит тоже. Что означает `_ => ...`, да то-же самое что и `() => ...` и то-же самое что `function () { return ... }` просто записано на короткую руку.

Comment: Я правда не пойму куда нужно вставить preventDefault() в тернарном выражении .

Comment: Проще подумать почему он у тебя Form.submit делает при нажатии на кнопку...  Либо на кнопке стоит `<button type="submit">` либо `<input type="submit">` либо где-то эвент стоит `button.addEventLister('click', event => event.target.form.submit())` проверь что привязано к onclick. И там будетпонятно.

Comment: Да ты был прав спасибо работает .